# How do I improve ALSA performance (or apply low latency) to real time Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, real-time

ALSA project homepage contains "Low latency howto" pagae.
The link is below.

https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Low_latency_howto

Unfortunately, this is too old because this is written for Linux kernel 2.6.

I am actually working on "Debian 9" with "Linux kernel 4.9".
I try to apply real time patch for kernel 4.9 and it is success.Then, following the instruction of "Low latency howto" page step-by-step, I set the kernel configuration.  I have not applied any kernel options pointing by the page because they does not exist.

I make kernel with real time patches and it is complete.

I adjust some settings follow the instructions of "System Tuneage"chapter.

- ALSA does not build from sources because it is already include kernel.
- I add some setting to PAM (/etc/security/limits.con).
- Some users who use audio add to the audio group.

Finally, I arrive at the "Thread Priorities" capter. However, I could not find "IRQ threads" as well as "hrtimer threads" despite of executing "ps -e"; i.e. "softirq-timer" and "softirq-hrtimer" does not exist.
So I can not complete applying thread priorities.

My question is,

Which threads should be prioritized on new Linux to apply low latency to ALSA ; e.g. kernel 4.9.
Otherwise, please let me know if anyone knows another better solution.

Thank you,

Comment: Don't know about Debian but Ubuntu has easy installable real time kernels, the default in Ubuntu Studio. Never heard of patches for that.

Comment: Hi, Gabriela ! Thank you for your answer. Debian 9 does not include real time patches. So I get patches from rt (i.e. real time) sub project of kernel.org. and  apply it to Debian 9. I do not know about that Ubuntu Studio has real time kernel. I consider your suggestion. Thank you,

Comment: Yes, suggestion in comments, not an answer. If I intended to answer your question I would have used the answers field. But I won't because I can't.

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you. Yes, I understand what you said (You just comment to question). Thank you kindly pointed out ;-) I will give it a positive consideration as plan B.